# Second Div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

My page works that the html site is loaded into div, and I was trying to add a feature that will refresh only that div when the page is reloaded using F5 and I acomplished a half success, when I add something into the html and press F5 the div reloads but only on some occasions, it works somehow strange to be honest, like five minutes it works and another five it don't. I read some articles about it and friend of mine told me that it has something to do with cache. Something like the browser when reloaded stores the site and when the change is made it last him longer to reboot it? Can you enlighten me in this? How the cache exactly work or what should I do different? This is my code

```
<script>
var d; 
function jauto(date) {
        $(function(){
        $("#mydiv").load("articles/201506"+date+".html"); 
        d=date;
    });


        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 116 ||e.keyCode == 116|| e.keyCode == 82 && e.ctrlKey) { 
                $("#mydiv").load("article/201506"+d+".html"); 
                 return false;
                 }
    });
}
</script>
```

Thanks for anything that could help me.

Comment: You use a button to set the date value? at what moment you set date value?

Comment: ` <a href="#" onClick="jauto('01')"> 1</a>` It's the day of the month - this is set for everyday, when clicked, loads the html site from article folder and puts it into div

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is to do with the browser caching your static HTML page. I think you have 2 options.set the below meta within your HTML that will instruct the browser not to cache the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

2. Append a random/unique query string every time while making the request to fool the browser into thinking it's a new request and to reload positively on refresh. This is done as below:

```
      <script> var d; 
function jauto(date){(function(){
   ("#mydiv").load("articles/201506"+date+".html"+
'?q='+(new Date()).getTime() ); 
d=date; });
(document).keydown(function(e) { 
  if (e.which    == 116 ||e.keyCode == 116|| e.keyCode == 82 &&    e.ctrlKey) {

        ("#mydiv").load("article/201506"+d+".html"+    '?q='+(new Date()).getTime() ); 
return false; 
} }); } 
</script>
```

Sorry for the bad code formatting